# React Gridstack this.cellHeight is not a function

Tags: reactjs, gridstack

I'm totally new to react with the exception of a few tutorials on some basic things so I feel I've thrown myself into a bit of a deep end here.

I'm trying to use gridStack and found a nifty wrapper for it to use within React. I've managed to struggle through getting all the dependancies up and running but have now encountered an error which I can't resolve:
`this.cellHeight is not a function(...)`. I've been looking around loads to try and understand why this isn't defined as I'm following their basic addition on their site [found here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-gridstack).

I've had to modify it a bit to make it play nice as I've whittled down all the errors and found this to be the last one which I just can not get my head round. Any help would be amazingly appreciated.

```
import React from 'react';
import GridStack from 'gridstack';
import {GridStackItem} from 'react-gridstack';

class MyGrid extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <GridStack cellHeight={50} vertical={10}>
                <GridStackItem id='item_1' x={0} y={0} minHeight={2} minWidth={2}>
                    First Item
                </GridStackItem>
                <GridStackItem id='item_2' x={0} y={2}>
                    Second Item
                </GridStackItem>
            </GridStack>
        );
    }
}

export default MyGrid;
```

The component is then being applied through my App class

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';
import Bootstrap from 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import MyGrid from './gridstack.jsx';

window.$ = $;

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <p>Hello WORLD!!!!</p>
            <MyGrid/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

You can see that this is all basic first steps kind of stuff as I find my feet around React.

Comment: I have a similar issue, I get 

Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _jquery2.default)(...).gridstack is not a function though i am including gridstack a bit differently in App.js:

import { GridStack, GridStackItem } from 'react-gridstack';

When I change to your way of including the module I get the same error as you :D